# Replace all a in the middle of string by * using regex

Tags: python, regex, replace

I wanted to replace all 'A' in the middle of string by '*' using regex in python
I tried this

```
re.sub(r'[B-Z]+([A]+)[B-Z]+', r'*', 'JAYANTA ')
```

but it outputs - '*ANTA '

I would want it to be 'J*Y*NTA'

Can someone provide the required code? I would like an explanation of what is wrong in my code if possible.

Comment: In the middle of a string or word? If a word is meant, use `r'\BA\B'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the non-wordboundary [\B](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).
To make sure that the A's are surrounded by word characters:

```
import re
str = 'JAYANTA POKED AGASTYA WITH BAAAAMBOO '
str = re.sub(r'\BA+\B', r'*', str)
print(str)
```

Prints:

```
J*Y*NTA POKED AG*STYA WITH B*MBOO
```

Alternatively, if you want to be more specific that it has to be surrounded by upper case letters.  You can use lookbehind and lookahead instead.

```
str = re.sub(r'(?<=[A-Z])A+(?=[A-Z])', r'*', str)
```

Comment: It's because your code also got the characters surrounding the A into the match. And thus replaced those with nothing.  That's where the lookarounds are handy, because those don't get included into the match, it's just a check if it's there.

Comment: The reason your regex gave '*ANTA ' as output is because after replacing 'JAY' with * there was no other match.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?!^)[Aa](?!$)','*','JAYANTA')
'J*Y*NTA'
```

My regex searches for an A but it cannot be at the start of the string (?!^) and not at the end of the string (?!$).

Comment: Replace all the `A`s inside the string, not at the start or end of it: *I wanted to replace all 'A' **in the middle of string** by '*'*

Comment: There is a space at the end of the string. In this case, your regex replaces the last A.

Answer (score 1):

Lookahead assertion:

```
>>> re.sub(r'A(?=[A-Z])', r'*', 'JAYANTA ')
'J*Y*NTA '
```

In case if word start and end with 'A':

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=[A-Z])A(?=[A-Z])', r'*', 'AJAYANTA ')
'AJ*Y*NTA '
```

Comment: Good solution, but would crop the `A` if it would be at index 0 in the string.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder for that case you need to check both side `>>> re.sub(r'(?<=[A-Z])A(?=[A-Z])', r'*', 'AJAYANTA ')
'AJ*Y*NTA '`